# Every real number has a decimal representation.

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2625318/340973) answer explaining why all real number have a decimal representation. I think it is really a nice explanation but I don't really see were (I think it is a little hidden) we use the density of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb R$ (which I think somehow we should use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the linked answer is virtually a **proof that** $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. It shows that a subset of $\mathbb Q$—fractions with denominators which are powers of $10$—has elements arbitrarily close to any real number. Which makes the same true of $\mathbb Q$, thereby proving that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

So the reason it doesn't use density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ is that it proves it instead.

Comment: Oh, l see. I could use the same reasonning for base b, where $b \ge 2$ but instead of dividing the interval into $10$ pieces I divide in $b$ pieces right? For example for base $2$ I just choose if the number is in the left or right of the interval.

Comment: Yes, you'd be doing essentially the same thing but end up with a representation in base $b$.

Answer (score 0):

It is used nowhere in that proof and I see no reason why it should.